# Suitable metrics for summarizing or visualizing the spatial activation of components after temporal Independent Component Analysis (ICA)

Tags: signal-analysis, decomposition

I will first describe the Independent Component Analysis (ICA) steps, so that the question becomes clearer, and more relevant to similar questions.

Assume we have $N$ sensors distributed in space. From each sensor we obtain a time series of length $T$. We collect these time series as rows in an $N \times T$ matrix $X$. After performing ICA we obtain a decomposition of the form $X = DS$, where $D$ is an $N \times N$ matrix of weights, and $S$ is an $N \times T$ matrix whose rows are the independent sources. To find the contribution of the $i$-th component to the observed signal we then multiply the $i$-th column of the matrix $D$ with the $i$-th row of $S$. The result is an $N \times T$ matrix which we will denote as $X^{i} = D_{*,i}S_{i,*}$. Then we can write: $X = X^{1} + ... + X^{i} + ... + X^{N}$.

In many domains I see single-picture visualizations of the spatial activation of the $i$-th component from ICA. However, it is not clear to me what metric to extract from each row of $X^{i}$ or from matrix $D$ in order to do this. Is it a summary statistic of the rows of $X^{i}$, e.g. the energy of the signals (rows) of $X^{i}$, the weighting coefficients from the $i$-th column of $D$, or something different altogether?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you put up such a picture of the spatial activation  of an i-th component that you are seeing? Each row of the $X_i$ matrix will have a (spatially) scaled version   the $i$th original signal.

Comment: For example, this is a picture with the activation per component (32 sensors and components) from ICA-decomposed EEG data: [ICA EEG](http://sccn.ucsd.edu/mediawiki/images/thumb/8/8b/94reject_ICAcomp.jpg/450px-94reject_ICAcomp.jpg). What does "spatially scaled" mean?

Comment: Sorry, can't edit my comment above. By "spatially scaled" do you mean that the $i$-th source signal is scaled (because of its distance to the source) to construct each row of the $X^{i}$ matrix? If so, the single value that is used for the sensor $k$ in the visualizations is the weight from the $i$-th column and $k$-th row of $D$, $D_{k,i}$, right? Then for the visualization of the $i$-th component, for each sensor $k$ we assign at its location in the image the value $D_{k,i}$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Firstly, what units does the heatmap in the image represent?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not specified in the tutorial of the toolbox where the image comes from ([EEGLab ICA tutorial](http://sccn.ucsd.edu/wiki/Chapter_09:_Decomposing_Data_Using_ICA)). The image comes automatically out of the ICA analysis, but it is not clear how it is computed.

Comment: I think the first thing to determine is the unit used in the heatmap. Let us say for the sake of argument that the heatmap was measuring energy, and let us inspect the top left image, which shows $X_1$. Then, each of the 32 sensor locations in the first (top left) image would be the energy of each row of $X_1$, which is $\sum_n X_{1,*}^2$. Make sense? But you need to figure out what units are being measured. Then we can easily back-track and extract that from each row of $X_i$.

Comment: It makes sense, this was my initial guess. Yes, if we find the units the solution can be easily reverse-engineered. However, apart from that particular example, do you think energy is a suitable metric for the purpose of showing "spatial activation" of the components?

Comment: Actually, I think its simpler: The spatial activation seems like it would simply be each element of each column of $D$. For example, for the top left picture, that would correspond to the first column of $D$, and each of the 32 sensors on the top left image would simply have a value equal to the element of the first column of $D$. In this way the heatmap is measuring the 'degree of activation' signal $1$ has on the 32 sites, for the first mixture.

Comment: I think using the elements of the column of $D$ is simpler and makes more sense. If you like you can put your comments as an answer and I will upvote it. Thanks for the helpful conversation!

Comment: You're welcome! Sometimes all that's needed is to talk it out with someone. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we know from the instantaneous mixture model of ICA, a signal mixture $X_{N,T}$ is composed of an unknown mixing matrix $D_{N,N}$, and an unknown signal matrix $S_{N,T}$, where:

$$
X = DS
$$

In ICA, we solve for $D_{N,N}$ and $S_{N,T}$ via maximization of absolute kurtosis. (As one method).

If we now look at the $i$th column of $D$, each element therein will now give us weight by which the $i$th signal gets weighted by in all $N$ mixtures. That is, each element $D_{n,i}$, (row $n$, column $i$), gives us signal $i$'s contribution to mixture $n$.

[image]

Those are called 'spatial weights' simply because in many ICA applications, we are de-mixing signals that sample a spatial field at different locations. Thus, each element of a column $D$ corresponds to a weight *in space*, that weighs signal source $i$.

In this way, we can show those weights in space as the heatmap above shows, and find the weight each signal gets weighted by, for a particular mixture, at different locations in space.